# What to return if a function has an error?

Tags: c, return-value

```
gcc 4.5.1 c89
```

I have a function that assigns the elements of the following structure:

```
static struct Config_t {
    char protocol[LINE_SIZE];
    char mode[LINE_SIZE];
} *app_config = NULL;
```

The function using malloc and memset to assign and clear the memory.

Once that is done, I have functions that gets the individual elements:

```
char* get_mode()
{
    if(app_config->mode != NULL) {
        return app_config->mode;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Here I am checking that a value has been assigned. And returning NULL if it hasn't. So in the calling function I can check if a NULL is returned. However, if there a better way to do this?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: I'm out of practice with C, but `mode` can't be `NULL`, can it? `app_config` can certainly be `NULL`, but your `mode` is defined as an array, an intrinsic part of the struct, not as a pointer. You'll either have the struct, or not, but you won't have *part* of the struct. If `mode` were defined as a `char * mode`, that would be different.

Comment: just return the mode: `return app_config->mode;` without checking it.

Comment: @T.J Mode is an array. However, that will decay into a pointer. I was just wondering what to return if the mode element for example as not been assigned any value. Thanks.

Comment: whenever you have a `Config_t`, there is an array within it; there is no possibility of it not having a value.  You don't need to assign to arrays.  In fact, you can't.

Comment: The `mode` symbol's type is certainly `char[]`, which is very similar to `char*`, but not the same. But my point is that it can't be NULL. What it defines is a *part of* the structure, not something separate that you need to allocate. Allocating the structure creates the `LINE_SIZE` chars of storage that `mode` references. See the quasi-off-topic part of my answer for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, returning `NULL` for an error condition is standard practice for functions returning pointers, so you're in good shape there. (For functions that don't return pointers, the usual convention is to return `0` on success and a non-zero error code on error.)

---

Separately, and perhaps a bit off-topic: `mode` can't be `NULL`, though, can it? `app_config` can certainly be `NULL`, it's a pointer to a structure, but your `mode` is defined as an array, an intrinsic part of the struct, not as a pointer. You'll either have the struct, or not, but you won't have only *part* of the struct. Simply allocating the memory for the struct will allocate the `LINE_SIZE` chars for `mode`; in fact, `sizeof(struct Config_t) == LINE_SIZE + LINE_SIZE`, the structure *is* an array of characters followed by another array of characters. There are no pointers involved (other than `app_config`, because you've defined it as a pointer to the structure).

Consequently, to fully allocate your `struct Config_t`, just do this:

```
app_config = malloc(sizeof(*app_config));
```

(or `app_config = malloc(sizeof(struct Config_t));` if your platform won't allow the above.) That allocates `mode`, nothing else required.

If `mode` were defined as a `char *`, that would be different:

```
static struct Config_t {
    char *protocol;
    char *mode;
} *app_config = NULL;
```

Now `sizeof(struct Config_t) == 2 * sizeof(void*)` (see below), the structure itself consists only of two pointers, not any data that they may point to. Allocating the structure does *not* allocate any storage for them.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LINE_SIZE (200)

struct Config_t {
    char protocol[LINE_SIZE];
    char mode[LINE_SIZE];
};
struct Config_t_with_pointers {
    char *protocol;
    char *mode;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("sizeof(struct Config_t) = %zu\n", sizeof(struct Config_t));
    printf("sizeof(struct Config_t_with_pointers) = %zu\n", sizeof(struct Config_t_with_pointers));
    return 0;
}
```

*(Given your compiler, I felt free to use the `z` format specifier for `size_t` arguments, as any recent gcc has it [and it's in the C99 standard, Matthew tells us].)*

Output (on my 64-bit Linux system):

```
sizeof(struct Config_t) = 400
sizeof(struct Config_t_with_pointers) = 16
```

Comment: T. J., your comment above is correct, so I would mention it here.  Any time you have a valid `Config_t`, you have a mode array within it.

Comment: J., `size_t` is standard C (C99).

Comment: J., sorry, I meant the `z` length modifier too.  I actually checked the modifier before, but then posted a vague comment. :)  It's in 7.19.6.1/7.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the definition of built in C functions, such as gets(), returning NULL is the ideal way to indicate that it was not possible to make an assignment or allocation.

Comment: I realize it now that you mention it. I guess gets has lots of downside to it right? I mean, on some C compilers we get the warning, gets() is a dangerous function :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, since the only reason that this happens is one (if no value has been assigned), you don't need more than one value to distinguish between them.
Also, NULL is no valid pointer, so I don't see anything wrong with that.

If you had more possible errors, you could use errno.h for that purpose.